# Show that $\overline{\overline{X}} = \overline{X}$ for all subsets $X$ of a metric space $S$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have to prove this and I am not sure how to go about it. Help please

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your definition of closure? I've seen two or three equivalent statements.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: $\overline X$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $X$; in particular $\overline X$ is closed. Having that, what is the closure of a closed set?

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$How you prove this will depend on what you already know about closed sets. If you know already know that for any set $A$,

$$\cl A=\bigcap\{F\subseteq X:F\supseteq A\text{ and }F\text{ is closed}\}\;,$$

then you should use Matemáticos Chibchas’s hint. If not, one approach is to prove the hint and then use it. Another, though, is to work directly with whatever definition you have.

For instance, you may have defined $\cl A$ to be the set of all points $x\in X$ such that every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A$. Then in order to show that $\cl\cl A=\cl A$, you need to show that if $x\in X$, and $U\cap\cl A\ne\varnothing$ for every open nbhd $U$ of $x$, then $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$ for every open nbhd $U$ of $X$. To do this, suppose that $U\cap\cl A\ne\varnothing$ for every open nbhd $U$ of $x$, and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$. By hypothesis there is some $y\in U\cap\cl A$. Clearly $U$ is an open nbhd of $y$, and $y\in\cl A$ so $U$ must contain ... what?

Answer (score 3):

The following supposes that your definition of $x \in \overline A$ is something to the effect of $B ( x ; \epsilon ) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ (or, equivalently, for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $y \in A$ with $d ( x,y) < \epsilon$).  If so, the following fact may be helpful:

> Given $x \in S$ and $\epsilon > 0$, for each $y \in B ( x ; \epsilon )$ there us a $\delta > 0$ such that $B ( y , \delta ) \subseteq B ( x , \epsilon )$.

Comment: Of course you know how this is helpful, but given the lack of upvotes, my guess is people don't see that clearly how this can help. You're claiming that every open ball is a nbhd of each of its points, i.e. that open balls are open, if we take the definition of open as a set which is a nbhd of each of its points.

Comment: @Peter: You're probably right, but given that Brian has basically followed this hint until the penultimate step, I'm honestly considering just deleting this answer.

Comment: Well, I think the edit just does it. +1